# Can I use web stack to develop native apps on Windows Phone 7, just as on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Windows 8 apps can be developed using web stack(JavaScript, HTML, CSS) or .NET stack(C#, C++, Visual Basic, XAML). What's the situation for Windows Phone 7 development?

Comment: http://htmlappwp7.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/ does not say anything about it, so I expect the answer is no for WP 7.5

Comment: @PavelMinaev This HTML App Host Framework for Phone 7 looks very interesting and fairly easy to use! The page says there's one app already in the Marketplace using this framework - do you know which one it is?

Answer (score 1):

WP7 doesn't have built in support for building apps with HTML/CSS/JS in the same way as Win8 but you can do a very similar thing with http://www.phonegap.com/

(WP7 support still in beta.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with Visual Studio 2011.
As mentioned in the Build Conference Keynote a week ago, windows 8 metro style app (using either stack mentioned) can be changed into windows phone app with very few changes of codes.

Comment: To be honest (I was at the BUILD Conference) I doubt it. A Metro App will use the the WinRT classes and these are not available on the Windows Phone. The only code that is easy to migrate were the domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will most likely happen with Windows Phone 8 (Apollo).